# Angular resolver unauthorized call

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am using ngrx/data and in order to set the store, i use resolver.

**user.resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  loading = false;
  constructor(private userEntityService: UserEntityService) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.userEntityService.loaded$.pipe(
      tap(loaded => {
        if (!loaded) {
          this.userEntityService.getAll();
        }
      }),
      filter(loaded => !!loaded),
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

**user.routing.ts**

```
  path: '',
    component: UsersComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: UserResolver
    },
```

The problem is when I use resolver, my Auth interceptor doesn't attach token to headers.
When i comment the "resolve" out, everything works fine. All the requests are authorized.

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
 const userProfileStr = localStorage.getItem('userProfile');

    if (userProfileStr) {
      const userProfile: User = JSON.parse(userProfileStr);
      const jwtToken = userProfile.jwtToken;
      const csrf = userProfile.csrf;

      let headers = new HttpHeaders();

      headers = req.headers
        .set('Authorization', jwtToken)
        .set('x-csrf-token', csrf)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      const cloneReq = req.clone({ headers });
      return next.handle(cloneReq);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Do you provide resolver in the same module that has interceptors?

Comment: Make sure that the `HttpClientModule` is provided in **one place**, along with the interceptors. And also make sure that the http client used by `userEntityService` is the one provided in that _one place_.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue , did you figure out the issue?

Comment: @user6392608 Yes, check your HttpClientModule. Where it is imported.